# Helper code to write to firebug logs, that doesn't break if using IE/Chrome etc

Tags: javascript, logging, firebug

Is there any helper code out there that will allow me to write to firebug's log window, but at the same time not break if using IE/chrome etc.

Answer (score 4):

Put this at the top of your first JavaScript include:

```
if(console === undefined) var console = { log: function() { } };
```

Comment: +1 This is a pretty good suggestion.  You could also do `var console = console || { log: function () {} };`

Answer (score 1):

A simple check for existence should work.

```
if ("console" in window)
    console.log("Log message!");
```

PS Chrome and IE7/IE8 have a console :-)